# Multifile upload

Tags: php, mysql

Looking for the following solutions:

Form html / php provide the ability to add multiple graphic files (up to 11 files, max 5MB).

When sending to a server script should do the following:

- check if the file has a good extension (jpg, png);
- re-name each file according to the formula < string up to 32 characters > _ < 000 to 010 >. < extension >;
- add file names to the table (one file = one column, row);
- compress to a maximum resolution of 1280x1024;
- change the proportions of graphics on 4: 3 images while maintaining the same proportions;
- lessen the size of the file and save to the server in the appropriate folder.

I'm interested in possibly easy to use solution.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Show the code which you have started with

Comment: I am currently looking for a components. 
Not yet started to write code.

Comment: @d0m1n1k_ You're looking for a complete code solution to your problem without showing any attempts at it yourself?

Comment: As I wrote looking for ready-made components.<br />
Myself am weak in writing code, and sometimes rewriting and adapting gives me a lot of problems.<br />I found a few solutions using jquery but not one I can use.<br />The most I like http://www.dropzonejs.com/ and http://www.plupload.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it,

**HTML Code**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multiple File Ppload with PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png");
$max_file_size = 1280*1024; 
$path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I thank you for that. Admittedly I was not able to reach complete happiness but your code is a good begin. With further adjustments should no longer cope alone.